# How to Display a Default Username if no Username is Entered in Signalr Chat

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Using the SignalR Getting Started Application at site code.msdn.microsoft.com/SignalR-Getting-Started-b9d18aa9, how would I change the default display from the big dot to "Anonymous" when user clicks okay without entering a username?

I'm new to javascript. I've searched through the code for username references and dots to no avail. For instance, in the default.html file below the line (about #40):

`$('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''))`

I added:

```
if ($('#displayname').val() != '' || $('#displayname').val() == null)
        {
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''))
        }

        else if ($('#displayname').val() == null || $('#displayname').val() == '') {
            $('#displayname') = "Anonymous";
        }
```

However, this isn't getting the job done.The dot still displays. Can anyone please give me some direction as to how to make this change to display "Anonymous"? Thank you.

Comment: Oops! Meant to comment to Greg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't read your example, however if the `UserName` being created through the server-side method `name`.  Then you'll want to do the following:

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
{
     Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
}
```

Then you should attempt the following when you call `Send`.

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
{
     var user = name;
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
          user = "Anonymous";

     Clients.All.broadcastMessage(user, message);
}
```

That in theory could resolve your issue, since JavaScript isn't resolving your issue.

However, I believe the following on the client side would be the stem of your issue.

```
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
        var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

        $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
            + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
    };
```

Inside there you could correct your invalid `username`.  Hopefully that resolves or points you in the right direction.  Without more information relevant to where your calling, I won't be much help.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful attempt to answer my somewhat confusing question, @Greg. I realized later that the "dot" I referred to actually displays with any person's chat comment on the app in question, whether they added their username or not. I figured out that I need to set the username to display as "Anonymous" by adding an if statement in the ChatHub.cs file of the app. Thank you again for your efforts.

Comment: Here's my final response: Thank you for your thoughtful answer to my confusing question, @Greg. I realized later that the "dot" I referred to actually displays with any person's chat comment on the app in question, whether they added their username or not. I put your if statement suggestion into the ChatHub.cs class and it worked to display the "Anonymous" username. Thank you again!